# Filter duplicate videos on Twitter

Tags: twitter

With Twitter, one can search for tweets with a video and a keyword.

For example, on twitter.com search for `bitcoin`, click *More options* on the left, and select *Videos*.

The problem is that the same videos appear over and over. Can I filter out duplicate videos?